# Attaching a new tab without use of "Title"

Tags: automation, uipath

I have a piece of automation that uses a handful of links to traverse to a required new tab. Once that tab is open, another set of rules handles how to utilize it. The problem is the site I am using has completely different names for each tab that is opened this way. I have tried attaching the browser with just a "*" for the HTML title (in hopes that it grabs the most recent active tab), but this doesn't seem reliable. I know you can capture the browser instance and pass it around as a parameter, but I haven't seen where I can grab the instance of the newly opened tab.

To maybe make this easier to follow:
attach browser
click a bunch of links
final link opens a new tab, with essentially a random title

another piece of code needs to pickup where the last one left off
so if I can either get the instance of the new tab to pass to the second set of code, or a way to attach the new tab to second set of code without the use of the "title"

I hope this makes sense. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, you have a browser, with a website. On that page you click on links to open them in new tabs. So far so good. Now you would like to switch to these new tabs.

So as there is no way to solve this in UiPath, I could think about a workaround that works in any browser without any plugin.

Steps to solve it:

1. Having all new tabs opened and the base tab is active in your browser
2. Get the tab title via `Get Attribute` activity and save it as String variable `MainTabTitle`
3. Now add a `Do While` loop
4. In the loop you add the following things:

   1. If you use Firefox, add the Hotkey `CTRL+Tab`, this will let you go to the next tab
   2. Add a `Get Attribute` activity (that extracts the title of the tab)
   3. Save the name into a `Dictionary` or something similar with an `Assign` activity
   4. Do this until you reach the first tab again (you can determine the first tab with checking your `MainTabTitle`)
   5. Then at the end of the `Do While` loop you now have the logic:

      1. We should have now all the tabs (except the first) in the Dictionary
      2. Now take the `title` of the first entry of that Dictionary
      3. That `title` is now used as the `Attach browser` scope that you need to use to give the tab the focus

That's it. I would say a proper way to solve this.